# Sort a List of StackPanels by GrandChild

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have a `List` of `TreeViewItem`s which contain `StackPanel`s as `Header`s.If I used `string`s inside those headers, I could use a line like

```
  tempList = tempList.OrderBy(a => a.Header.ToString()).ToList();
```

But now `Header` is a `StackPanel`, the `StackPanel` has an `Image` and a `TextBlock`. `TextBlock` contains a Run. And I want to sort the tempList by these 'Run.Text'...

Anyone an idea how I could do this?

Comment: Could you provide a XAML code next to your question ?

Comment: I dont use a XAML-template here. It is all made programmatically. It would look like this i believe: <StackPanel><Image src="..." /><TextBlock><Run Text="abc" /></TextBlock></StackPanel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found it out by myself. I thought it would be harder.

```
tempList = tempList.OrderBy(a => ((Run)((TextBlock)((StackPanel)a.Header).Children[1]).Inlines.FirstInline).Text).ToList();
```